# Renaming a duplicated value in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

I am trying to remove a duplicate column value in a pandas dataframe. So for example:

```
2019-03-31
2019-06-30
2019-09-30
2019-12-31 
2020-03-31
2020-03-31
```

notice 2020-03-31 is duplicated. I would like to find the duplicated date and rename it as `last quarter`

conversely, If the column has no duplicates I want to leave as is. Can someone guide me in the right direction to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without loops

```
series = pd.Series(['2019-03-31',
           '2019-06-30',
           '2019-09-30',
           '2019-12-31', 
           '2020-03-31',
           '2020-03-31'])

series.loc[series.duplicated()] = 'last quarter'
```